# Is RDS available in Azure same like amazon for SQL server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-sql-database

I want to setup SQL server automated backup and I like the RDS but my client wants to go with the Azure but I checked on that but I didn't found anything like RDS in Azure.

Is RDS available in Azure same like amazon for SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

Tushar

RDS is a Amazon technology , In Azure you can run MYql.SQLServer ,Oracle . Azure SQL Database , very much like RDS

To you are specific question , what's the version of SQL Server you are looking.

If you are using , SQL 2014 , then it provides SQL Server Managed Backup to Windows Azure, you just need to provide 
1.Retention period settings 
2.Storage location (Azure Blob)

Then , Windows Azure schedules, performs and maintains the backups.

Also there are 3 party vendor to explore that can backup your database.

http://sqlbackupandftp.com/

Let me know if it answered your question.